# Как добавить заголовок в Activity?

Tags: java, android

Как добавить заголовок в `Activity`? В превью `xml` разметки заголовок виден, но при запуске программы его нету. 
Так же `<include>` не подходит, потому что в меня есть выездное меню и оно перекрывает этот обьект

Comment: Не хватает информации. Нужны ваша разметка, стили, и объяснение более четкое желаемого поведения.

Comment: И **никогда** не пользуйтесь `превью xml`. Оно всегда врёт.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб как это врёт?

Comment: @RedShaman, оно не способно учесть всех нюансов стилей, аттрибутов и фантазии программиста. Оттого и показывает всякую кривоту. Тестировать надо только на девайсе/эмуляторе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Превью показывают не обязательно ту тему, которая установлена для `Activity`, а ту которая в просмотрщике установлена.
Установите в качестве темы приложения/`Activity` любую с наличием `ActionBar`
В android manifest в теме укажите в теге приложения:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

или конкретной `Activity`

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Answer (score 3):

Для заголовка нужен минимум `Android 3.0` и тема `Holo`. Добавляй это в манифест:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

И сменить тему надо на `Holo`.

Также есть люди которым помог это ( надо добавлять на манифест):

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" >
```

Comment: в наше время модна тема AppCompat (Material Design)